# When I try to click on the button it is not working

Tags: jquery

When I click on the button,the function is not called

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#Add_Image').click(function () {
    window.open('upload.html');
  });
</script>

<button id="Add_Image" style="margin:10px; width:200px; height:35px; border-radius:8px;"> Add Image</button>
```

Comment: You're missing a `document.ready` or you have to reorder the element and the script tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write it inside document ready part:

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Add_Image').click(function () {//you can use  $('#Add_Image').on('click',function () { //also
    window.open('upload.html');
    });
    
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="Add_Image" style="margin:10px; width:200px; height:35px; border-radius:8px;"> Add Image</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The below works fine for me... just wrap in document.ready, and don't use underscores or capitalisations on selector names ;-). That will prob cause a debate :-/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#add-image').on('click',function () {
        window.open('upload.html');
    });

  });
</script>

<button id="add-image" style="margin:10px; width:200px; height:35px; border-radius:8px;"> Add Image</button>
```